# Message encryption and decryption code in Paython

Tags: python

I am working on Brian Heinold's book A Practical Introduction to Python Programming where exercise 23 in chapter reads "A more general version of the above technique is the rail fence cipher, where instead of breaking things into evens and odds, they are broken up by threes, fours or something larger. For instance, in the case of threes, the string secret message would be broken into three groups. The first group is sr sg, the characters at indices 0, 3, 6, 9 and 12. The second group is eemse, the characters at indices 1, 4, 7, 10, and 13. The last group is ctea, the characters at indices 2, 5, 8, and 11. The encrypted message is sr sgeemsectea.
(a) Write a program the asks the user for a string and uses the rail fence cipher in the threes case to encrypt the string.
(b) Write a decryption program for the threes case.
(c) Write a program that asks the user for a string, and an integer determining whether to break things up by threes, fours, or whatever. Encrypt the string using the rail-fence
cipher.
(d) Write a decryption program for the general case."

My encryption code is:

```
message = input("Enter a message: ")
part = eval(input("Enter the encryption interval, e.g. by threes, fours, etc. "))
encrypted = ""

for chunk in range(part):
    for i in range(chunk, (len(message)), part):
        encrypted = encrypted + message[i]

print(encrypted)
```

which works. But I am still struggling with the code that would convert the encrypted message back to its original shape.

```
message = input("Enter a message: ")
part = eval(input('Into how many parts the cyoher was split? '))
length = len(message)
block = length//part
decrypted = ""

for k in range(0, length, part):
    for i in range(block):
        for j in range(part):
            section = message[part + i]
            decrypted = decrypted + section

print(decrypted)
```

I guess it's the iterations that cause the confusion. Please advise where I went wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: Try manually encrypting a short test case. Let's say 20 letters in a 4x5 box. Do you think the same function could be used for both encrypt and decrypt? You might have to pad a few spaces.

Comment: Also write functions so you don't have to deal with user input until you're actually writing the final program. Unit testing on a known test case is much easier. Looks like we don't actually have to pad.

Comment: @KennyOstrom, thank you for your comments. At this stage I'm looking for a simple solution to decrypt 'aaabbbccc' into 'abcabcabc'. I must have messed up my loops.
When I was looking for a solution I discovered that many coders prefer to use functions for such cases. The reasons I avoided it is because in the book that I'm learning from functions come somewhere close to the end. So I go with the curriculum.

Comment: Well, function or not, you may be over-complicating the decrypt. I'm serious about doing it on paper to see how the encrypt and decrypt are really just the same thing. Rotate it 90 degrees.